# imagemagick dark text and bold

Tags: php, imagemagick

Using imagemagick below image text need dark and bold .[image]

And using imagemagick give below image remove other than text and number like black spot and border. example given below

[image]

Comment: Great ! ... And what is your question ?

Comment: here i want o do these thing using Imagemagick

Comment: i am just update my question.

Comment: So you want to create a pseudo-intelligent image processor that knows what is considered 'junk' from 'good' and have it remove such? Well... I applaud you for the ambition, but thats above my pay-grade (of zero for free help on so) ;)

Comment: IncredibleHat  : No thanks dear i really appreciate if you can help me because here i need help if i need pay-grade developer then i will post in upwork or freelance.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, you can use morphology erode to make the text thicker.

```
convert input.png -morphology erode diamond:1 output.png
```

[image]

For the other image:

```
convert input.png -morphology dilate "1x5:0,1,1,1,0"  -morphology erode diamond:2 output.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it's working Bro can you help me in 2 question border remove?